# change year of datetime column by the year of another column + 1

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the **anniversary column** by this way : keep the date and month, and change the year to the same year as **start column** + 1

**This is my pandas dataframe :**

```
| index |   start       |      end       |     anniversary|   
| ----- | -----------   | -------------- | -------------- | 
| 0     |   2008-02-11  |    2009-03-13  |   2009-02-11   |     
| 1     |   2009-03-13  |    2010-03-13  |   2009-02-11   |     
| 2     |   2010-03-13  |    2011-03-15  |   2009-02-11   |
```

**What i want to get :**

```
| index |   start       |      end       |     anniversary|   
| ----- | -----------   | -------------- | -------------- | 
| 0     |   2008-02-11  |    2009-03-13  |   2009-02-11   |     
| 1     |   2009-03-13  |    2010-03-13  |   2010-02-11   |     
| 2     |   2010-03-13  |    2011-09-19  |   2011-02-11   |
```

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the `start` and `anniversary` columns?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dt.year` to get the year component of the datetime in `start` column then increment it by `1` and change the `dtype` to `str`. In the similar way, extract the `month` and `day` components from the `anniversary` column. Finally concat all the individual components and use `pd.to_datetime` to convert back to `datetime`:

```
year = df['start'].dt.year.add(1).astype(str)
month_day = df['anniversary'].dt.strftime('%m%d')

df['anniversary'] = pd.to_datetime(year + month_day, format='%Y%m%d')
```

---

```
>>> df
           start         end anniversary
index                                   
0     2008-02-11  2009-03-13  2009-02-11
1     2009-03-13  2010-03-13  2010-02-11
2     2010-03-13  2011-03-15  2011-02-11
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun an one-liner implementation:

```
out = df.assign(anniversary=pd.to_datetime(pd.concat(
          [df["start"].dt.year + 1, df["anniversary"].dt.month, df["anniversary"].dt.day],
          axis="columns").set_axis(["year", "month", "day"], axis="columns")))
```

```
>>> out
       start        end anniversary
0 2008-02-11 2009-03-13  2009-02-11
1 2009-03-13 2010-03-13  2010-02-11
2 2010-03-13 2011-03-15  2011-02-11
```